# Plotly.js in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, definitelytyped

I've tried to use the plotly.js in Ionic 2 using the @types/plotly.js found here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/plotly.js

To test this I'm using the test code found in the upper link. This code does work without Ionic after using 'tsc' and 'browserify'. If I'm trying to run the ionic command 'ionic serve' I get a webpage with the following error:
"Runtime Error: It appears that you're using glslify in browserify without its transform applied. Make sure that you've set up glslify as a source transform: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browserifytransform

Does anyone has any experience with using plotly.js in Ionic 2?

Thanks in advance,
Ronald